# how to call the real static method by using junit Mockito test case?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

i need to call the actual static method from the junit test method using mockito , even i am using spy to that class to call actual or real method . I am not able to call that real method .

here is my actual method,

```
public class Utility {

public static JSONArray getDefaultPage(Set<String> files){
    JSONArray pageNames = new JSONArray();
    try {

        //code will go here
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return pageNames;
}
}
```

here is my testCase,

```
@PrepareForTest(Utility.class)
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class UtilityTest {
@Before
public void setupMock() {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Utility.class);
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
@Test
public void getDefaultPageListTest(){
PowerMockito.when(utilityMock.getDefaultPageList(reqSet)).thenReturn(respList);
    utilityMock.getDefaultPageList(reqSet);

}
```

}

here is my whole code , when is not able to call the real method .

Comment: update the question with the code that you have tried so far,  so that we can help you better

Comment: @pvpkiran , i wrote my code what i tried so far

Comment: Which version of powermockito, mockito are you using?

Comment: @NikhilBhide powermockito 1.6.6 and junit 4.12